# Android development, how to load only sector on a map?

Tags: android, dictionary, fragment, sector

I'm a newbie and i have a question. I'm developing a Map Application. But i only want to load a sector on a map, not all whole world. (for example: only New York city instead of all America). Can you help my with a clue, a tutorial, or just a "key word", then i can find it.
Thanks for your help !
(And sorry for my English)

Comment: may be it can done with offline feature of google map ... by precache map area

Comment: :( i'm using GPS and network state, i dont' know how to tranfer offline application, could you give me a "key word" for that

Comment: comment is full of "key words" ... precache map area , offline feature of google map ...